# Проблема при установке GoCV на Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, golang, opencv, cmake

Хотел попрактиковаться в OpenCV + TensorFlow + Go, но стакнулся с проблемой:
для Go есть замечательный биндинг OpenCV [GoCV](https://godoc.org/gocv.io/x/gocv), он понятно требует OpenCV. Его я оставил используя Homebrew, ошибок не было. Но при установке GoCV вылетела вот такая:

> # gocv.io/x/gocv
>       gocv.io/x/gocv/core.cpp: In function ‘cv::Mat* Mat_ConvertFp16(Mat)’:
>       gocv.io/x/gocv/core.cpp:70:5: error: ‘convertFp16’ is not a member of 
>       ‘cv’
>       cv::convertFp16(*m, *dst);
>       ^

Потом я закомментировал эту строку и пошло дальше, но вылетела ещё одна ошибка:

> # gocv.io/x/gocv
>       In file included from gocv.io/x/gocv/dnn.cpp:1:0:
>       gocv.io/x/gocv/dnn.h:8:27: fatal error: opencv2/dnn.hpp: Нет такого 
>       файла или каталога
>       compilation terminated.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне быть.
P.S. OpenCV и все зависимости homebrew поставил в свою директорию `~/.linuxbrew/Cellar`

.pc файлы homebrewскладывал в `~/.linuxbrew/lib/pkgconfig`

include'ы здесь `~/.linuxbrew/include`

переменные среды ставил с `env.sh`, [вот они](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6w3zdm971qs4pfn/env.txt?dl=0)

есть пакеты `libopencv-contrib-dev`, `libopencv-contrib2.4v5`, `libopencv-dev`, `libopencv-contrib-dev`, `libopencv-core-dev`, `libopencv-core2.4v5`, им принадлежат `/usr/include/opencv/` и `/usr/include/opencv2/`, но с ними при `go get gocv.io/x/gocv` вылетает

> # gocv.io/x/gocv
>       gocv.io/x/gocv/core.cpp: In function ‘cv::Mat* Mat_ConvertFp16(Mat)’:
>       gocv.io/x/gocv/core.cpp:70:5: error: ‘convertFp16’ is not a member of 
>       ‘cv’
>       cv::convertFp16(*m, *dst);
>       ^

пробовал копировать директории `~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/opencv` и `~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/opencv2` в `/usr/include`, удалив те папки opencv- [ошибки](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qawmjjsa5oyahod/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0.txt?dl=0)
но вспомнил, что закрывал терминал после `source env.sh` и выполнил команду ещё раз - [ошибки](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oi4lcg6a12kcrr0/%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Какая версия OpenCV?

Comment: opencv 3.4.1_2 @Fat-Zer

Comment: А системная при этом второй версии случаем не установлена?

Comment: @Fat-Zer была. удалил, но  появилась новая ошибка `# gocv.io/x/gocv
In file included from gocv.io/x/gocv/core.h:24:0,
                 from gocv.io/x/gocv/core.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:51:35: fatal error: opencv2/photo/photo.hpp: Нет такого файла или каталога
compilation terminated.`

Comment: `opencv2` намекает, что не [полностью] удалил... хинт: наверно `*-dev` пакет остался... и не забудь переконфигурировать после.. ЗЫ:. а вообще вместо удаления желательно было бы просто правильно сконфигурировать, но с деталями здесь я не помогу...

Comment: @Fat-Zer полностью удалил opencv2, но заметил две вещи: gocv требует opencv нуден второй версии т.к. везде инклудается `opencv2/*.hpp/.h`  и то, что opencv3 по непонятным причинам не установлен. Может-быть подскажите, как можно поставить opencv 2?

Comment: я кстати заблуждался: `opencv2/*` — это слой совместимости с предыдущей версией из третьей ветки... по ссылке прямым текстом написано, что это биндинги к третьей версии, так что вряд ли откат получится... на данном этапе я бы попробовал заново накатить третью...

Comment: @Fat-Zer переустановил opencv с помощью brew. но мне кажется он не до конца его поставил т.к. папка opencv есть в директории homebrew (.linuxbrew/Cellar/opencv), но в директории  /usr/include её нету и следовательно GoCV при установке выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: не пользовался homebrew... по идее он не должен был бы портить системный префикс, а ставить всё куда-нибудь в `/usr/local`... если так и если сборка в Go основана на `pkg-config`, то скорее всего будет достаточно просто экспортировать в среду `PKG_CONFIG_DIR="$PKG_CONFIG_DIR:<prefix>/lib/pkgconfig/"` (или куда он там `*.pc` файлы сваливает?..)

Comment: @Fat-Zer поставил путь, перекинул дополнительно содержимое директории /.linuxbrew/Cellar в /usr/include, но при go get вылетает милkион ошибок типа  `Документы/apps/go/src/gocv.io/x/gocv/imgproc.cpp:133:28: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
         points[i] = Contour{pts, (int)contours[i].size()};
                            ^
# gocv.io/x/gocv
/tmp/go-build950348528/gocv.io/x/gocv/_obj/core.cpp.o: In function cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
`

Comment: `source`'нуть  [env.sh](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/blob/master/env.sh), а лучше самостоятельно установить все переменные не забыл? ЗЫ: ручное механическое перемещение каталога — не самая светлая мысль...

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё сделал, [но](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qawmjjsa5oyahod/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0.txt?dl=0)

Comment: гм... похоже снова от 2.4 хедеры пробились... по крайней мере если верить git'у, то `Cv32suf` была удалена из `opencv2/core/types_c.h` во времена мажорной смены версий...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это всё конечно очень здорово, но что делать то?

Comment: @Fat-Zer пробовал docker образ dymat/gocv, но вылетает та-же шибка

Comment: ещё раз расскажи по порядку, с конкретными именами и путями, что и где находится? в какой префикс homebrew установил библиотеку? какой путь до include'ов? куда он положил *.pc файл? какие переменные среды и с какими значениями установлены вручную или с помощью `env.sh`? есть ли системные пакеты, которым принадлежат файлы `/usr/include/opencv*`? ЗЫ: всю информацию можно добавить в вопрос...

Comment: @Fat-Zer не очень понял, что за includeы?

Comment: хедеры, включаемые файлы, которые, будучи системными, обычно устанавливаются в /usr/include.

Comment: @Fat-Zer всё, добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, для начала переменные в env.sh из коробки не подходят, попробуй следующие:

```
# только для удобства дальнейших команд
export OPENCV_PREFIX="$HOME/.linuxbrew"
# здесь можно опустить часть до двоеточия включительно.
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$OPENCV_PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OPENCV_PREFIX/lib"
# вероятно тут можно поставить 11,14 или 17 для более определённого результата
export CGO_CXXFLAGS="--std=c++1z"
```

После этого стоит убедится, что `pkg-config` видит правильную версию opencv:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.4.<что-то там>
$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
-I/<path/to/my/home>/.linuxbrew/include
$ pkg-config --libs opencv # строки после -L может и не быть.
-L/<path/to/my/home>/.linuxbrew/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_face -lopencv_videoio ...
```

Если вывод pkg-config удовлетворительный, то его можно использовать для остальных переменных:

```
export CGO_CPPFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --libs opencv)" # Если нет "-L*", то можно вписать путь к библиотекам вручную.
```

В противном случае стоит проверить правильность установки `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. Если настроить `pkg-config` ни как не получается, то можно задать переменные вручную:

```
export CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I$OPENCV_PREFIX/include"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L$OPENCV_PREFIX/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_face -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_xfeatures2d"
```

При этом значение `CGO_LDFLAGS` избыточно и его следует урезать в соответствии со своей установкой/потребностями.

Comment: очень благодарю! помогло, вы спасли меня от запоя!

Comment: есть [проблема](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho0qqm4cl7tx4od/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0.txt?dl=0), но `libgtk2.0-dev` установлена

Comment: это уже где-то надо гладить homebrew, что бы он `opencv` с поддержкой gtk собрал... Если кратко, то нужно передать `-DWITH_GTK=ON` и, вероятно, `-DWITH_GTK_2_X=ON` `cmake`'у... также возможно потребуется `-DWITH_OPENGL=ON`, а также может быть сработает, если собрать с `Qt` вместо gtk (-DWITH_QT=5 для сборки с пятым кьютом)...

Comment: спасибо, поменял формулу и всё заработало, но есть ещё вопрос не по теме - сейчас запустил пример `tf-classifier` и получил просто ужасный FPS! точно не считал, но ооочень мало. Может подскажите способ оптимизации или мне надо плюсы учить?

Comment: это лучше уже в отдельном вопросе спросить, не забыв описать, что это и зачем оно нужно... желательно сравнив с производительностью на C(++) и краткой инструкцией, как это воспроизвести... из вариантов — для начала посмотреть где узкое место... учитывая предыдущую историю, возможно всё вычисляется на процессоре из-за того что библиотека собрана без openCL, а может быть openCL как-то неверно сконфигурирован и библиотека не смогла корректно его инициализировать... если видимой нагрузки вообще нет, то я бы грешил на тормоза камеры или там просто может быть какая-то искусственная задержка в коде.

Comment: снова здравствуйте! решил начать работать с еensorflow, но оказалось, что этот фреймворк [не работает](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2csgme1ob3gmls/%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20tensorflow.txt?dl=0) с Golang 1,6. НО gocv и другие биндинги типа go-opencv [работают ТОЛЬКО с golang 1,6!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/df4ezpo4ctym05p/%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20gocv.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @Mr.Blaze, извини вот с этим уже я скорей всего не помогу — это проблема исключительно в епархии go. Сборка всякого странного FOSS'а мне интересна, а вот с go я дел практически не имел... ЗЫ: добро пожаловать в dependency hell... Как вариант, можешь попробовать более старую версию gocv — он вроде не вчера родился, наверняка более старые версии рассчитаны на младшие же версии go.